# SharePoint 2013 list column title modification with javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to modify SharePoint 2013 list column title in views with javascript. There is a code I found here at stackoverflow, but I want to reference the column with the display name / internal name, not with the column position.

```
(function () {


    function preTaskFormRenderer(renderCtx) {
       modifyHeaderData(renderCtx);       
    }


    function modifyHeaderData(renderCtx)
    {
      var viewTitle = renderCtx.viewTitle;
      var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[1];
      linkTitleField.DisplayName = viewTitle + ':' + linkTitleField.DisplayName;
    }

    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPreRender: function(ctx) {

        var field = getFieldByDisplayName(ctx,"Task Name"); 
        if(field)
            field.DisplayName = "Task Name:::"; 
     }
   }); 

});


function getFieldByDisplayName(ctx,name)
{
    var result  = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f){return f.DisplayName == name;} ); //find field by display name
    return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
}
```

Result

[image]